# density of the product of two random variables

Tags: probability, self-learning

Suppose I have two random variables:

$X_1$ and $X_2$ have densities $f_\theta = \theta x^{\theta - 1}$

I want to find pdf of $Y = X_1 X_2$

$$
P(Y\leq y)= P(X_1X_2\leq y) = \int_0^1 \theta P(X_1\leq y/x) x^{\theta - 1} \, dx = \int_0^1 \left(\frac y x \right)^\theta x^{\theta -1} \, dx
$$

Density is derivative, so:

$$\int_0^1 -\theta x^{\theta - 2} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^\theta \, dx$$

Is it correct calculations? If not, please tell me, where did I do a mistake

Comment: $$ \int_0^1 \left(\frac y x \right)^\theta x^{\theta -1} \, dx = y^\theta \int_0^1 \frac{dx} x \quad \text{ since } \left(\dfrac y x \right)^\theta x^{\theta-1} = y^\theta\cdot \dfrac 1 x. $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you for your help! and as I understood $y^\theta$ must be a constant?

Comment: As far as the integral with respect to $x$ is concerned, $y$ is a constant since it does not change as $x$ goes from $0$ to $1. \qquad$

Comment: In the intermediate step where you calculating $\Pr\{X_1 \leq y/x\}$, make sure you are aware of the support of $X_1$ - the CDF is a piece-wise function, depends on the argument $y/x$.